# TransactionScope with same context

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

Is it ok for me to write such EntityFramework code for the transactions:

```
using(var trans = new TransactionScope())
{
    using(var context1 = new MyDbContext())
    {
        context1.AddEntity(...);
        context1.SaveChanges();
    }

    using(var context2 = new MyDbContext())
    {
        context2.UpdateEntity(...);
        context2.SaveChanges();
    }

    trans.Complete();
}
```

What I want to achieve is put above two operations as one unit (it's just a demo, in real situation, those two are separated by different services, so they cannot reuse the context), any of them fail will rollback.

Are above code enough?

Comment: Is there a problem with your code?

Comment: This will use MSDTC. That's slow and does not work with mirroring/AG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have written your example, **yes** it will work.

In your question you mention

> in real situation, those two are separated by **different services**, so

It depends what type of services you mean. If you mean WCF services, then you also need to configure your WCF service correctly. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384250.aspx) and/or [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730232(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.